# Front-End Filtering React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have filtered the products and on submitting the search term, am showing the results in a new page using history.push() property.

```
   import React, { useState } from 'react'; 
   import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
   import { IoIosSearch } from 'react-icons/io';
   import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
   import './style.css';

  /**
  * @author
  * @function Search 
  */

  const Search = (props) => {    

  const product = useSelector(state => state.product);

  let { products , filteredProducts } = product;

  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

  const onChangeSearch = (e) => {
     setSearchTerm(e.currentTarget.value);
  }

  const isEmpty = searchTerm.match(/^\s*$/); 

  if(!isEmpty) {
    filteredProducts = products.filter( function(prod) {
        return prod.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase().trim())
    })    
}
  const history = useHistory();

  const display = !isEmpty    

  const handleSubmit =(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();   
    
    if( !isEmpty ) {       
        history.push(`/search/search_term=${searchTerm}/`, { filteredProducts })
    }

    setSearchTerm('');
}
 return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="searchInputContainer">
                    <input
                        className="searchInput"
                        placeholder={'What are you looking for...'}
                        value={searchTerm}
                        onChange={onChangeSearch}
                    />
                    <div className="searchIconContainer">
                            <IoIosSearch 
                                style={{
                                    color: 'black',
                                    fontSize: '22px'
                                }}
                                onClick={handleSubmit}
                            />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            {
                display && <div className="searchResultsCont">
                    {filteredProducts.map((prod, index) => (<div key={index}>{prod.name}</div>))}
                </div>
            }                
        </div>

);
}
export default Search
```

On the new page this is the code :

```
     import React from 'react';
     import Layout from '../../components/Layout';

     const SearchScreen = ({location}) => {

     const products = location.state.filteredProducts;

     const show = products.length > 0

     return (
        <Layout>
        <div>
            { 
                show ? products.map((prod, index) => (<div key={index}>{prod.name}</div>)) : <div>No items found</div>              
            }
        </div>
       </Layout>
    )
  }

 export default SearchScreen
```

The problem comes when I copy and paste the URL to another new page, or like when I email others the URL the error becomes  **" Cannot read property 'filteredProducts' of undefined "**. Using this method I understand that the results (filtered products) have not been pushed through the function history.push() that's why it is undefined, how can I make this possible?

Comment: could you show us the entire code ?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the whole aspect to filtering the products from the back-end..
It worked